# Pivot Selected Rows in R

Tags: r, tibble

I have a question regarding pivoting. If I have a dataset which I scrape from the web and only gave me all the data in column, how can I pivot the data to their specific column: example

| Column |
| --- |
| Date |
| Number |
| Additional Number |
| 2022-08-10 |
| 2,4,5,6 |
| 7 |
| 2022-08-11 |
| 2,4,5,3 |
| 11 |
| 2022-08-12 |
| 2,4,5,8 |
| 14 |

The ideal output of the table would be:

| Date | Number | Additional Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-10 | 2,4,5,6 | 7 |
| 2022-08-11 | 2,4,5,3 | 11 |
| 2022-08-12 | 2,4,5,8 | 14 |

Comment: are you familiar with modulo method? add a column that repeats a number count that resets where they should be a new row. in your example, every 4 rows so you can use the `%%` and `row_number()` to get that. Then you can simply `pivot_wider` with `names_from` the modulo column and the `values_from` the column wiith the values.

Comment: thats what I did actually, I thought is there another efficient way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `matrix` to reshape the vector. In case the data is stored in a `data.frame` of one column subset this columns to get a vector (e.g.`DF$s`).

```
matrix(s[-1:-3], ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, s[1:3]))
#     Date         Number    Additional Number
#[1,] "2022-08-10" "2,4,5,6" "7"              
#[2,] "2022-08-11" "2,4,5,3" "11"             
#[3,] "2022-08-12" "2,4,5,8" "14"
```

If needed this could be converted to a `data.frame` with `as.data.frame`. If needed the type of the columns could be converted by using `type.convert`. If needed the column *Date* could be converted to `Date`.

```
. <- matrix(s[-1:-3], ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, s[1:3]))
. <- as.data.frame(.)
. <- type.convert(., as.is=TRUE)
.$Date <- as.Date(.$Date)
str(.)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Date             : Date, format: "2022-08-10" "2022-08-11" ...
# $ Number           : chr  "2,4,5,6" "2,4,5,3" "2,4,5,8"
# $ Additional Number: int  7 11 14
```

As in the comments a solution using `tidyr::pivot_wider` was expected:

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(data.frame(v=s[-1:-3], cn=s[1:3], row=0:(length(s)-4)%/%3),
                   values_from = v, names_from = cn)[-1]
#  Date       Number  `Additional Number`
#  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>              
#1 2022-08-10 2,4,5,6 7                  
#2 2022-08-11 2,4,5,3 11                 
#3 2022-08-12 2,4,5,8 14
```

Data

```
s <- c("Date","Number","Additional Number","2022-08-10","2,4,5,6","7",
       "2022-08-11","2,4,5,3","11","2022-08-12","2,4,5,8","14")
```

---

Benchmark

```
bench::mark(check =FALSE,
matrix = matrix(s[-1:-3], ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, s[1:3])),
pivot_wider = tidyr::pivot_wider(data.frame(v=s[-1:-3], cn=s[1:3], row=0:(length(s)-4)%/%3), values_from = v, names_from = cn)[-1],
"Anoushiravan R" = {df <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, split(s, rep(1:(length(s) %/% 3), each = 3)))))
names(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
df <- df[-1, ]
row.names(df) <- NULL
df},
)
#  expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_a…¹ gc/se…² n_itr  n_gc total…³
#  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t>
#1 matrix           1.69µs   2.08µs   397335.      0B    0    10000     0  25.2ms
#2 pivot_wider      5.78ms   6.29ms      156.  34.8KB    6.32    74     3 474.4ms
#3 Anoushiravan R  84.62µs  91.95µs     9446.      0B   12.8   4436     6 469.6ms
```

Using `matrix` is in this case about **2500** times faster than using `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

Comment: This is a cool idea. I would have thought of only pivot_wider from tidyr. But your approach doesn't need any package at all.

Comment: I add a version using `tidyr::pivot_wider` but this is much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another try in base R if your original data is a data frame with one column:

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(do.call(cbind, split(df, rep(1:(nrow(df) %/% 3), each = 3)))))
names(df) <- as.character(unlist(df[1,]))
df <- df[-1, ]
row.names(df) <- NULL
df

        Date  Number Additional Number
1 2022-08-10 2,4,5,6                 7
2 2022-08-11 2,4,5,3                11
3 2022-08-12 2,4,5,8                14
```

Answer (score 0):

I am putting a more "classic" solution to the problem below. This involves the modulo method which is useful to unpivot data like this.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x=letters)
df %>% 
  mutate(modulo=row_number()%%4, #pattern repeats every 4 entries so i put a 4
         id=row_number()) %>% # row id
  pivot_wider(names_from=modulo,values_from=x) %>% 
  fill(3:5,.direction="up") %>% #leave the first column and fill direction up
  rename(col=2,col1=3,col2=4,col3=5) %>% #renamed the cols
  filter(!is.na(col)) #remove empty from first column
```